# Thymeleaf th:each noting include din template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, java-11

I have a Thymeleaf fragment which contains some status text and an th:each which does not appear in the output.
I have been able to include the model value in the output its a list<list> and is displayed as [[ 8,9...][..]...]] all the values are correct.
I have run with logging.level.org.thymeleaf=trace to get the logs, but it appears that nothing is wrong to me.

The fragment is:

```
   <span th:fragment="view">
    <div class="centered">
        <h1 th:text="${sudoku_description}"></h1>
        <h1 th:text="${sudoku}"></h1>
        <div class="centered" >
            <th:block th:each="puzzledata, rowStat : ${row}">
                <div class="sudoku-row" >
                    <th:block th:each="row, colStat : ${cell}">
                        <div class="sudoku-cell" row="rowStat.index" col="colStat.index" th:text="${cell}"></div>
                    </th:block>
                </div>
            </th:block>
        </div>
       </div>
    </span>
```

The 2  tag are present and correct but the following `<div class="centered" >` on inspection is empty.
I have tried changing the th:block to a div made no difference.
Running from Intelij no exceptions or errors in the console.

Thymeleaf log extract

```
[THYMELEAF] View sudoku-view :: view will be handled by ThymeleafViewResolver and a ThymeleafView instance will be created for it
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1][EXPRESSION_CACHE][CACHE_HIT] Cache hit in cache "EXPRESSION_CACHE" for key "expr|~{sudoku-view :: view}".
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Evaluating fragment: "~{sudoku-view :: view}"
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Evaluating generic token: "sudoku-view"
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Evaluating generic token: "view"
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] STARTING PROCESS OF TEMPLATE "sudoku-view::[view]" WITH LOCALE en_GB
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1][TEMPLATE_CACHE][CACHE_MISS] Cache miss in cache "TEMPLATE_CACHE" for key "sudoku-view::[view]".
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Template resolver match! Resolver "org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver" will resolve template "sudoku-view"
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1][EXPRESSION_CACHE][CACHE_HIT] Cache hit in cache "EXPRESSION_CACHE" for key "expr|${sudoku_description}".
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Evaluating variable expression: "${sudoku_description}"
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] SpringEL expression: evaluating expression "sudoku_description" on target
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1][EXPRESSION_CACHE][CACHE_HIT] Cache hit in cache "EXPRESSION_CACHE" for key "expr|${sudoku}".
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Evaluating variable expression: "${sudoku}"
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] SpringEL expression: evaluating expression "sudoku" on target
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1][EXPRESSION_CACHE][CACHE_HIT] Cache hit in cache "EXPRESSION_CACHE" for key "each|puzzledata , rowStat : ${row}".
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Evaluating generic token: "puzzledata"
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Evaluating generic token: "rowStat"
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Evaluating variable expression: "${row}"
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] SpringEL expression: evaluating expression "row" on target
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] FINISHED PROCESS AND OUTPUT OF TEMPLATE "sudoku-view::[view]" WITH LOCALE en_GB
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1][sudoku-view][en_GB][1127600][1] TEMPLATE "sudoku-view::[view]" WITH LOCALE en_GB PROCESSED IN 1127600 nanoseconds (approx. 1ms)
```

Comment: In spring boot are you adding value/list to `row` attribute which you are trying to loop through in html/thymeleaf? In html/thymeleaf does `${row}` have value?

Comment: More proof that stupidity rules - got the values in the each the wrong way round, should have been iterating over puzzledata producing row!
Spent 2 days trying to work out why it did not work, read the docs on th.each many times but as soon as I read your question illumination happened!
Thankyou Eric

Answer (score 1):

Everyday development day provides evidence of just how stupid one can be.

The problem was the values in the th.each wrong way round!

This works:

```
<th:block th:each="row, rowStat : ${puzzledata}">
```

This does not:

```
 <th:block th:each="puzzledata, rowStat : ${row}">
```